# Validate image size in pixels in h:inputFile

Tags: validation, jsf, file-upload

Is there a way to use `h:inputFile` to upload an image with an exact size in pixels, something like 300x200, and don't accept other image sizes? Is there any XML config to do this? I'm using JSF 2.2. I've read `h:inputFile` documentation and can't figure it out how to implement it.

Comment: See the stuff about using a validator: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/JSF2.2FileUpload/JSF2.2FileUpload.html

Comment: Why not proportionally rescale the image, and save that version? It costs, but the code is about five lines (ImageIO).

Comment: @Joop Eggen, I think you're right, it's more simple, just crop the image in photoshop and save it, thanks to @Davio too, I used that example to implement my `fileUpload`

Comment: Ah,I meant uploading a wrong sized image resulting the server saving it rescaled. This can be done with standard java, ImageIO.

Comment: But if it do a auto resize, the image it will be distorted, that's why I need to know if there is a way to restrict by size, just allowing an image in that specifc size, I find a way to filter by size(bits) not in pixels, I think that is not possible at all

Answer (score 0):

Like @JoopEggen said, I'll resize or crop my images it's more simple